# Parse SOAP response with PHP/xpath - Cant step further than one node

Tags: php, soap, xpath

I've tried to read other tutorials & SO responses on this but I just can't seem to make it work :/

I'm able to make the SOAP request and get a response but I can't seem to parse the response.

```
$result = $client->GetAllAttributes($params);
```

And the resulting response xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <GetAllAttributesResponse xmlns="http://connect2.askadmissions.net/webservices/">
    <GetAllAttributesResult>
     <result>
      <code>1</code>
       <ErrorMessage />
       <returndata>
         <attributes>
           <attribute>
            <type>attribute</type>
            <level />
            <name>text1321</name>
            <mappingname><![CDATA[Extra-Curricular Interest]]></mappingname>
            <datatype>Varchar2</datatype>
            <size>35</size>
            <validationexp />
           </attribute>
           <attribute> (same as above, several of these are returned</attribute>
         </attributes>
       </returndata>
      </result>
     </GetAllAttributesResult>
    </GetAllAttributesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
 </xml>
```

I've tried

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($client->__getLastResponse());
print_r($xml);
```

But it just prints "SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) "

I've tried

```
$responseXML = $client->__getLastResponse();
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($responseXML);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('hob', 'http://connect2.askadmissions.net/webservices/');
        $item = $xml->xpath('//hob:GetAllAttributesResult');
        print_r($item);
```

and I get an array

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => <result><code>1</code><ErrorMessage /><returndata><attributes><attribute>    <type>attribute</type><level />
```

etc. (array is very long)

My problem comes when I try to step further into the tree. If I do

```
$item = $xml->xpath('//hob:GetAllAttributesResult/hob:result');
```

or

$item = $xml->xpath('//hob:GetAllAttributesResult/hob:code');

I end up with an empty array.

How do I step further into the tree?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the element's value, you need to access the first element of the array. And you may need to cast it to string to get the string value
e.g. in your example you can do:

```
$item = $xml->xpath('//hob:GetAllAttributesResult/hob:result/hob:code');
print_r((string)$item[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.  I tried your suggestion and it still seems to print nothing.

[Here](http://sandbox.ryantrattles.com/attributes.php) is an example that prints out from

    $item = $xml->xpath('//hob:GetAllAttributesResult');

It seems that anytime I step to a node after the first it breaks? Also, perhaps I'm misunderstanding this, but shouldn't all the items under the array in my linked example create additional arrays?

Comment: It works when I try it on my side. Except that I had to remove the last </xml> element from your example xml which makes the xml invalid and causes a parse error

Comment: Weird. I got it to work, but it seemed that everything inside GetAllAttributesResult was a string and I couldn't parse it. I had to pass it back in like this

    


`$item = $xml->xpath('//hob:GetAllAttributesResult');
   $newxml = simplexml_load_string($item[0]);`



And then I could continue walking down the tree :/ weird. Thank you for the help.